# Qual o principal uso de decoradores em classes

Tags: python-3.x

Gostaria de entender mais sobre decoradores com classes, qual sua principal vantagem dentro de uma classe, quais os decoradores mais usados, se há alguma alternativa a eles, e como saber quando usalos de forma eficiente;
Eu entendo como funcionam, mas gostaria de me aprofundar mais neles.